# Countdown using DateTime UNITY AD

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I want there to be 15 minutes between the rewarded ads. I made this:

- When you see the ad:

> ```
> public void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward args)
>     {
>         DateTime ad= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
>
>         long adTicks = ad.Ticks;
>         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ticksVideo", (int)adTicks); }
> ```

- Countdown:

> ```
> void Update(){   
>
>         DateTime currentTime= DateTime.Now;
>         long currentTicks= currentTime.Ticks;
>         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("currentTicks", (int)currentTicks);
>
>         TimerControl = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("ticksVideo") - PlayerPrefs.GetInt("currentTicks");
>
>         string mins = ((int)TimerControl / 600000000).ToString("00"); //600.000.000 ticks per minute
>         string segs = ((int)TimerControl % 600000000).ToString("00");
>         TimerString = string.Format("{00}:{01}", mins, segs);
>         GetComponent<Text>().text = TimerString;  }
> ```

In DateTime.Now.AddMinutes I enter 15 but the countdown lasts about 50 seconds. On the other hand, the TimerString also does not show the format that I indicate. What's wrong? Should I use TimeSpan?

Edit:

I have 2 classes:

- The player watch the ad:

> ```
> public class AdMob : MonoBehaviour
> {
>    public static bool video = false;
>    public Button buttonAd;
>    public GameObject countdown;
>
>    public void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward args)
>     {
>         //Rewards
>         buttonAd.interactable = false;
>         countdown.SetActive(true);
>         video = true;
>     }
> }
> ```

- The countdown begins:

> ```
> public class CountdownAd : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     public static float timeSinceLastAd = 0;
>     void Update(){
>     if (AdMob.video)
>         {
>             timeSinceLastAd += Time.deltaTime;
>             if (timeSinceLastAd > (60 * 15))
>             {
>                 buttonAd.interactable = true;
>                 countdown.SetActive(false);
>                 timeSinceLastAd = 0;
>                 AdMob.video = false;
>             }
>         } else
>         {
>             timeSinceLastAd = 0;
>         }
>
> }}
> ```

EDIT 2:

```
 public class AdMob : MonoBehaviour {
        public GameObject countdownGameObject;
        public Button adButton;
        public Text countdown;

        //I hit the adButton and I watch the rewarded ad...
        public void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward args)
        {
            //Rewards..
            countdownGameObject.SetActive(true);
            StartCoroutine(timer(15));
            adButton.interactable = false;
        }

        IEnumerator timer(int lapse)
        {
            while (lapse > 0)
            {
                int seconds = lapse % 60;
                int minutes = lapse / 60;
                countdown.text = $"{lapse / 60: 00}:{lapse % 60:00}";
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
                lapse--;
            }
            countdown.text = "00:00";
            //CountDown Finished
            gameObject.SetActive(false);

            if (lapse == 0)
            {
                adButton.interactable = true;
                countdownGameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Where is the statement that calls the method that will show the ad?

Comment: The ad works perfectly, only the countdown fails

Comment: Yes but how do I know how the countdown fails if I don't know when it kicks off the ad?

Comment: The countdown works but not as it should. It shows something like this: 62342542:00 and lasts less than it should. I don't think the problem is anywhere else

Comment: what is not clear is what is GameObject, what is canvas what is uiText..and what scripts is linked with what GameObject, UIText  or Canvas??? i suppose the video is displayed in canvas?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Don't worry about the GameObject, all of that works fine. The only thing that fails me is the countdown operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a sample of countdown  linked to the UIText displaying the countdown, i am using a StartCoroutine launched from Start() and dont use Update()

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Countdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Coroutine coroutine;
    private Text UITimer;
    void Start()
    {
        UITimer = GetComponent<Text>();
        if (coroutine != null) StopCoroutine(coroutine);
        coroutine = StartCoroutine(timer(60*15));

    }

    IEnumerator timer(int lapse)
    { 
        while (lapse > 0)
        {
            UITimer.text = $"{lapse / 60:00}:{lapse % 60:00}";
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            lapse--;
        }
        UITimer.text = "00:00";
        //CountDown Finished
        gameObject.SetActive(false);

        // and all other things
    }
}
```

Comment: The first time it runs, it works perfectly, but when I start the countdown a second time, the countdown value is 0. What I want is a button that starts the countdown and when it reaches 0, I can hit the button again and the countdown starts again

Comment: ok i dont know how you call the countdown..that is i dont understant in my comment question

Comment: Ok, I have implemented what you have told me, look at the second edit

Comment: How do I start the coroutine again with that value?

Comment: now i know how you luanch the coroutine just stopcoroutine before relaunch i have modified my code.

Comment: Ok, it works. You are the best, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks confusing, keep a timer and increment it with Time.delaTime each frame, when the timer is > 15 minutes play ad and reset timer.

```
float timeSinceLastAd = 0;

void Update(){
     timeSinceLastAd += Time.deltaTime;
     if (timeSinceLastAd > (60 * 15)) {
     PlayAd(); //or whatever your method to play an ad is called
     timeSinceLastAd = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: I have edited it explaining it better and using what you told me, but it does not work

Comment: I watch the video and I can watch it again. The countdown does not start and the button is interactable.

Comment: I have finally solved it, thank you very much for your help Vasmos!